# how exit bash in one line, kind of pipe it in exit (no bashfile)

Tags: bash

I want to run something in bash, so

```
sh <do something> exit
```

Is there a way to pipe in what I want to do via command line and not using a bash file? Reason being the code doesn't use a file, but just a command, and for testing I'd rather have control what that command is to make it do nothing without changing the code.

Bit weird I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in `sh -c "your_command your_args"` ...?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

echo 'ls -l' | sh

Should be able to do anything within those quotes, subject to normal shell escaping/wildcarding rules.

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
 eval "$YOURSTUFF; exit"
```